# Is it possible to dump inode information from the inotify subsystem?

Tags: hook, inotify, inode, rootkit

I am trying to figure out what files my editor is watching on.
I have learnt that **count the number of inotify fds** from `/proc/${PID}/fd` is possible, and my question is: Is it possible to **dump the list of watched inodes by one process**?

UPDATE:
I have updated one working solution, and thanks for a helpful reference [here](https://uwnthesis.wordpress.com/2016/12/26/basics-of-making-a-rootkit-from-syscall-to-hook/).

UPDATE 2: well, recently I found `kallsyms_lookup_name` (and more symbols) not export since `Linux Kernel v5.7`, so I decide to update my own solution if anyone else cares.

Comment: for user space implementation, please refer to `inotify node inverse map` in CRIU: https://criu.org/Irmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
With the help of `kprobe` mechanism used in [khook](https://github.com/milabs/khook) , I just simply hook the `__x64_sys_inotify_add_watch` and use `user_path_at` to steal the `dentry`.

The code snippet is listed below, and my working solution is provided [here](https://github.com/VDM-Maintainer-Group/vdm-capability-library/tree/main/inotify-lookup/inotify-hook).

```
#define IN_ONLYDIR          0x01000000  /* only watch the path if it is a directory */
#define IN_DONT_FOLLOW      0x02000000  /* don't follow a sym link */


//regs->(di, si, dx, r10), reference: arch/x86/include/asm/syscall_wrapper.h#L125
//SYSCALL_DEFINE3(inotify_add_watch, int, fd, const char __user *, pathname, u32, mask)
KHOOK_EXT(long, __x64_sys_inotify_add_watch, const struct pt_regs *);
static long khook___x64_sysinotify_add_watch(const struct pt_regs *regs)
{
    int wd;
    struct path path;
    unsigned int flags = 0;
    char buf[PATH_MAX];
    char *pname;
    // decode the registers
    int fd = (int) regs->di;
    const char __user *pathname = (char __user *) regs->si;
    u32 mask = (u32) regs->dx;

    // do the original syscall
    wd = KHOOK_ORIGIN(__x64_sys_inotify_add_watch, regs);
    // get the pathname
    if (!(mask & IN_DONT_FOLLOW))
        flags |= LOOKUP_FOLLOW;
    if (mask & IN_ONLYDIR)
        flags |= LOOKUP_DIRECTORY;
    if ( wd>=0 && (user_path_at(AT_FDCWD, pathname, flags, &path)==0) )
    {
        pname = dentry_path_raw(path.dentry, buf, PATH_MAX); //"pname" points to "buf[PATH_MAX]"
        path_put(&path);
        printk("%s, PID %d add (%d,%d): %s\n", current->comm, task_pid_nr(current), fd, wd, pname);
    }
    return wd;
}
```